# Figures displaying as empty boxes

Tags: graphics

I am inserting figures like this

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=.5\textheight, keepaspectratio]{howtorun.jpg}}
    \caption{{how to Run }}
\end{figure}
```

but this is what I get:

[image]

the settings width=.6\textwidth, height=.5\textheight are just from a document I am using as a template so I don't know if they make sense, made that's the reason? How do you come up with dimensions of a digital picture??? I mean if it is the computer it can adapt to any size in the page Any help would be very appreciated

EDIT: MY SETTINGS

```
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside,openright,cucitura,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,amsopn,dsfont}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\oddsidemargin 30pt
\evensidemargin 20pt
\linespread{1.3} %cambia le dimensioni dell'interlinea: 1.3=1,5 righe
%\usepackage{showkeys}
\pagestyle{headings}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example which allows us to reproduce your problem. The code fragments you show work fine after puzzling them together.

Comment: you are using the `draft` option, although you do not show that in your code

Comment: `cucitura` ?...

Comment: You can set [draft=false] in \includegraphics if necessary.

Comment: Possible use of `\setkeys{Gin}{draft}` in some package.